# Flow not figuring out argument type from typedef'ed return

Tags: flowtype

I have declared the type of the return, I am using redux action creator here as described in the tutorial on flowjs.org - https://flow.org/en/docs/react/redux/

```
type UpAsyncAction = { type:typeof UP_ASYNC, times:number };
const upAsync = (times=1): UpAsyncAction => ({ type:UP_ASYNC, times });
```

The `times` argument gets underlined saying as in this screenshot:

[image]

> parameter `times` (Missing annotation)

However I thought flow was smart and that it uses a graph algorithm, so it should be able to figure out that if the `times` is in the return and that `times` was used as an argument no?

Comment: The disadvantage of letting Flow figure things out is - that it figures things out. Meaning, whatever you actually do is the norm. Instead, you annotate to be _explicit:_ about your intent. This is enforced for function parameters but not much else (or nothing else? Not sure) because that's the "API". Example ordering in a restaurant: a) you accept whatever they bring you, b) you told them you wanted a cucumber salad so you complain when they bring you a tomato potato salad. If you hadn't said anything up front you would have to accept whatever there is. Having a spec vs. not having one.

Comment: About your assumption: it tests that, sure, but that is independent of asking you to specify types for all parameters. --- [In any case, I don't get an error with your example (**Flow Try link**)](https://flow.org/try/#0MYewdgzgLgBAqgBQPoEEDKBNAcgYRgXhgEYBuAKDKgE8AHAU3hpQirGBWCgEtwCYBvGNXoAuYXRAAzeMnTYcAGiFcAtnQgiwAVxUAjOgCcYAX3KhIsLUxZs+ACm5qI+IgEoRjZq3aceYAgB8MHaC4iKIqJi4So7qJq7kQA)?

Comment: Interesting thanks very much @Mörre - i wonder why vscode is telling me missing annotation whereas the "flow try it" link is not.